# creating button snapping using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a row of buttons 4 on the left of my screen

button button button button

When one of those buttons are pressed I want them to snap to the right of screen in a slow moving way like this, and visa versa

button button button ---->------------->--------->----->--------> button

This is my jquery code thus far

```
 $( ".nav-submenu-item" ).on('click',function() {
        $(this).animate({ 
            left: '90%'
          }, 500);
        $(this).animate({ 
            left: '0px'
          }, 1).delay(0).queue(function (next) {
            $(this).css("display","none");
    $(this).next().css("display","inline-block");
            next();
        });
    });

    $( ".nav-submenu-item-clicked" ).on('click',function() {
        $(this).animate({ 
            left: '-700px'
          }, 500);
        $(this).animate({ 
            left: '0px'
          }, 1).delay(0).queue(function (next) {
            $(this).css("display","none");
    $(this).prev().css("display","inline-block");
            next();
        });
    });
```

my css

```
.nav-submenu-item{position:relative; vertical-align:top; display:inline-block; font-size:.8em; color:#eaeaea; height:auto; width:auto; float:left; margin-left:15px; margin-top:10px; text-align:left; line-height:30px; font-weight:bold;}

.nav-submenu-item-clicked{display:none; vertical-align:top; font-size:.8em; color:#eaeaea; height:auto; width:auto; float:right; margin-left:15px; margin-top:10px; line-height:30px; font-weight:bold;}
```

and my php looks like this

```
<div class="nav-submenu-item">
    <div class="nav-submenu-icon">button</div>
</div>

<div class="nav-submenu-item-clicked">
    <div class="nav-submenu-icon">button</div>
</div>
```

the problems i have with this code is
1) it's not clean and the animation is also not clean
2) animation only works left to right, not right to left
3) the amount it's moving left to right is not correct because it's a fixed value, and obviously when one button snaps to the right or one buttons position moves on the left then it should adjust accordingly

I was really hoping for a simpler way to do this in Jquery but i've looked at heaps of documentation and tried to google an answer and can't find anything :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want the animation you need to have (margin-right) set to a value in your css. It only works one way because you have only defined (margin-left) in your css.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Syntastic. Not really. I added Margin-right into both my divs css and still not working right to left. Either way, surely there is a cleaner or better way to get the functionality i want?

Comment: maybe instead of using animate, use $('.yourelement').css({left: '-700px'});
and have in your css: transition: ease-in-out all 300ms;

Comment: is their a trick to getting the transition to work, because it does nothing for me? i've thrown them into both divs. Changed my jquery to reflect this

 $( ".nav-submenu-item" ).on('click',function() {
     $(this).css("display","none");
  $(this).next().css("display","inline-block");
});